# x86 disassembly confusion regarding VESA functions

Tags: ida, disassemblers, dos

I'm trying to disassemble an old DOS application and got stuck at some point of the VESA graphics handling.

The VESA function to be called will be stored in a global variable, e.g. `vesa_fct_dword_749C8 = 0x4f00`, `0x4f01`, etc.
After checking the return value, the application will do some additional magic, which I, frankly, don't understand. My guess is that it will check for a specific error return value (`0x01`, in particular), but I'm really not quite sure about it and how it's actually done.

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
cseg01:000159D8 loc_159D8:                              ; CODE XREF: checkForVesa+D4↑j
cseg01:000159D8                 mov     eax, vesa_fct_dword_749C8
cseg01:000159DD                 mov     edx, vesa_fct_dword_749C8
cseg01:000159E3                 sar     edx, 1Fh
cseg01:000159E6                 shl     edx, 8
cseg01:000159E9                 sbb     eax, edx
cseg01:000159EB                 sar     eax, 8
cseg01:000159EE                 and     eax, 0FFh
cseg01:000159F3                 cmp     eax, 1
cseg01:000159F6                 jnz     short loc_15A01
cseg01:000159F8                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0
cseg01:000159FF                 jmp     short loc_15A29
```

Maybe someone knows what's up with that part, that would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This code takes the most significant bit of `EAX` (`msb(EAX)`) and then, it subtracts it from `AH` and compares the result to `1`. According to [this specification](https://www.versalogic.com/Support/Downloads/pdf/69030bg.pdf) ("VBE Return Status" section):

- `AX = 014F` => `AH = 1` means "*Function call failed* "
- `AX = 024F` => `AH = 2` means "*Function is not supported in current hardware configuration*
  "

And the `jnz` instruction will be executed if `msb(EAX) = 1` and `AH = 2`, or when `msb(EAX) = 0` and `AH = 1`. Unfortunately, I don't know what information is stored in `msb(EAX)` (maybe something related to VBE version?).